# Change touchpad horizontal and vertical acceleration/sensitivity?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

How do I individually change the horizontal and vertical acceleration of the cursor? I can scroll side-to-side in a single stroke on a 1600x900 monitor on my laptop, but I can never do that vertically. Furthermore, the touchpad seems to be too sensitive horizontally (I hold my index finger still, but the cursor subtly moves)... is this fixable?

I'm using a Synaptics touchpad.

Comment: Having this same problem with an Apple Magic Trackpad and dual monitors in TwinView configuration at 3200x1600. Horizontal movements too sensitive compared to vertical ones; making a circle on the pad results in a wide horizontal oval movement on the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution for Ubuntu **11.04**:

Add the options

```
Option "VertResolution" "75"
Option "HorizResolution" "75"
```

To the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`.

After doing that, mine looks like:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "VertResolution" "75"
    Option "HorizResolution" "75"
EndSection
```

Now log off and log back in, and it should be fine! :)

Comment: That works for two screens for me!

Comment: Are there any new solutions to this question? Say for Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: You could try to play around with settings by using the program `xinput`, maybe it'll work for you.

Comment: It's ten years later and dual monitors still screws with touchpad behavior.  Not really able to comprehend why a decade of countless posts wasn't enough to get this extremely obvious issue taken care of...

Comment: @Metal450: I don't think my question had anything to do with dual-monitor setup?

Comment: Oops, apologies if I misinterpreted then - I've spent the past ~2hrs reading about this exact behavior, as caused by dual monitor setups (when you plugin a 2nd monitor, which increases the width of the 'virtual display', it doubles the touchpad's horizontal speed, making it unusable).  i.e. https://superuser.com/questions/308966/touchpad-sensitivity-scales-to-virtual-screen-dimensions.  So they're closely related, but I guess your issue was more generally about applying screen width to touchpad sensitivity. In my case, the issue appears when I plugin the 2nd monitor.

Comment: @Metal450: Haha yeah they could be related, not sure. In my case I just find the pointer ballistics awful on Linux.

Comment: For me, they were perfect (working on a small laptop) until I plugged in a 2nd screen.  The 2nd screen made the horizontal resolution 2x, which made the pointer go crazy.  So yeah, it's kinda the same issue: it should work properly regardless of resolution :/