# Synaptics Touchpad pointer speed change with additional screen

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, touchpad, synaptics, xinput

When I plug in an additional screen, the sensitivity of the touchpad scales with the virtual screen dimensions, making it unusable.

I can't imagine how this "feature" could be of interest to anyone, but whatever, I'd like to find a way to disable this.

Any idea ?

My conf :
Lenovo Y50
Synaptics touchpad
ubuntu trusty LTS

Comment: It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-driver-synaptics/+bug/726832) with a long history. This question appeared here several times already. You can check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28675/) post, for example. Maybe `xinput` fiddling may help.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor speed scales with the display size, I think. I have dual monitors, but I don't really notice it. The computer monitor's aspect ratio is most likely different than the external display's aspect ratio. If so, there's your problem, and the only way to solve it is to get a display that matches the laptop display's aspect ratio, or make the resolution of both displays the same.

EDIT: Both of my monitors have a 16:9 aspect ratio, so that explains why I don't notice the cursor speed changing.