# Alps touchpad vertical/horizontal resolution

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics, xinput, alps

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 500 14-ISK. Everything works as it should, except the touchpad. It does recognize multitouch, right clic (not zooming multitouch but I dont know if this is supported...)

The main issue is the touchpad seems to calibrate speed depending on the screen size/ratio, and since touchpad and screen havent the same ratio, it move faster in the X direction than Y. I already tried the solution here [Change touchpad horizontal and vertical acceleration/sensitivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28675/change-touchpad-horizontal-and-vertical-acceleration-sensitivity) but it doesnt work... 
My touchpad is recogized as
"AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" and "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick".

Also, something that worry me, is the command

`input list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" | grep Capabilities`

is returning "

`Synaptics Capabilities (330):  1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0`

In other words, the last two digits indicate the support for vertical and horizontal resolution cofiguration support. Here you can see that they are reported as 0, so xinput seems to not allow me to modify any of theses two parameters...

Thank you for reading and hopefully be able to help me :)

Comment: Is anyone able to help me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same problem on my Lenovo U31-70.

EDIT: [ It does show up in the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file: [Changes in 50-synaptics.config File have no effect. Are they being Overritten?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930061/changes-in-50-synaptics-config-file-have-no-effect-are-they-being-overritten) ]

`xinput --list` retuned
`↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint`

so i ran the same command as you did:

`xinput list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" | grep Capabilities`
returned:

`Synaptics Capabilities (300):  1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0`

I asked for some help over here: [I can't change vertical/horizontal resolution of my touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929223/i-cant-change-vertical-horizontal-resolution-of-my-touchpad)
but there does not seem to be a simple sollution.