# I can't change vertical/horizontal resolution of my touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I have changed settings in the `50-synaptics.conf` file as stated in this thread:
[Change touchpad horizontal and vertical acceleration/sensitivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28675/change-touchpad-horizontal-and-vertical-acceleration-sensitivity)

I have added:

```
Option "VertResolution" "75"
Option "HorizResolution" "75"
```

Have tried different numbers, but this does not seem to change anything for me.
Maybe it is not using the synaptics driver?
Using a Lenovo U31-70 and 16.04 LTS

EDIT: as requested
Output of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

EDIT 2: output of `xinput list-props 12`:

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint':
Device Enabled (140):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (266): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (268):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (269):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (270):  614, 3481, 307, 1740
Synaptics Finger (271): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (272):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (273):   201
Synaptics Tap Durations (274):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (275):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (276):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (277):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (278):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (279): -91, -91
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (280): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (281):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (282): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.043687, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (283):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (284):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (285):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (286): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (287):   1, 3, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (288): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (289):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (290): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (291):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (292): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (293):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (294): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (295):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (296): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (297):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (298):  0
Synaptics Gestures (299):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (300):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (301): 1, 2
Synaptics Area (302):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (303):  2047, 0, 1678, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (304): 22, 22
Device Product ID (261):    2, 8
Device Node (262):  "/dev/input/event5"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Now add the output of `xinput list-props 12`. Not all touchpads support resolution change.

Comment: It looks like the kernel driver does not support resolution change for this device.

Comment: just checked. it does show the change in in the `50-synaptics.config` file

`Synaptics Pad Resolution (301): 1, 4`

Comment: But it does not affect anything in reality. Maybe it affects vert/horiz ratio.

Comment: what do you mean by ratio? btw: huge thank you for helping me!